# How to batch highlight keywords on PDFs for free?

Tags: pdf, automation, pdf-editor

Considering that:

1. I'm doing a Systematic Literature Review;
2. the relevant information is so much easier to find when the keywords I need are highlighted that I must have this done;
3. however, manually highlighting keywords over dozens of PDFs is boring, time-consuming, and robotic;

Obs.: I'm talking about keywords' occurrence all over the article text, not just in the "keywords" section.

My questions are:

1. are there free software tools for doing batch highlighting on PDFs?
2. if they do exist, can you please point me at least one of them?
3. if you can point me at least one of them, can you please write, or point me a how to tutorial on using the tool for batch highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example free [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/) has that capability:

1. Open advanced search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).
2. Change destination to `All PDF documents in` and choose folder.
3. Choose `Match any of the words`.
4. Enter keywords.
5. Check `Whole Words Only` and `Highlight All Text` checkboxes.
6. Press `Search`.

Comment: Is not this "highlighting" only temporary while <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>is active, or is it permanent? I'm interested in editing the PDF, making a permanent highlight on the document.

Comment: Nothing in your current question suggests permamence/editing.

Comment: The question has a tag "pdf-editor".

Comment: But I created a new question anyway: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87703/how-to-batch-highlight-permanently-keywords-on-pdfs-for-free .

Comment: PDF editors can also search for text. Adding a random tag should never be a pointer towards what you want. The other question is much more accurate now.

Comment: Let's say that one of the keywords that I want is "expert systems". How to not highlight all occurrences of "expert" and "systems", but only occurrences of "expert systems"?

Comment: Use other search options to suit the search to your needs. The default is `Match exact word or phrase`